# Finding a probability mass function for $[x]$ is defined as the largest integer $n$ such that $n \leq x$

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

If $X$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$ and we have that $[x]$ is defined as the largest integer $n$ such that $n \leq x$.

If $Y$ is defined as $$Y = \left[ X\over a \right]$$ where $a>0$ then how would you find the probability mass function of $Y$?

Comment: What steps have you taken to address this problem? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Well I've worked out that $\mathbb{P}(X/a \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda a x}$ and then tried to say that if $x \in (n , n+1)$ then $\mathbb{P} ([X/a] \leq x)$ is the same as $\mathbb{P}(X/a \leq n+1)$ but I don't think this really helps!

Comment: You're on the right track but your conclusion is incorrect: for any constants $u\le v$, $\Pr(X/a \in (u,v])$ is equivalent to $\Pr(X \in (au, av])$. So how would you compute that probability for an exponential variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n \leq x$ won't suffice as it does not translate that n is the larger integer that fulfill the property.

you have to work with $n \leq x < n+1$.

$$P(Y=n) = P(n \leq \frac{x}{a} \leq n+1)$$
$$P(Y=n) = P(na \leq x \leq (n+1)a)$$
$$P(Y=n) = F_{x}((n+1)a) - F_{x}(na)$$

With the expression of the cumulative distribution function $F_{x} = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$

$$P(Y=n) = 1 - e^{-\lambda (n+1)a} - 1 + e^{-\lambda na}$$

$$P(Y=n) = - e^{-\lambda (n+1)a}  + e^{-\lambda na}$$

$$P(Y=n) = 2e^{-\lambda (n+\frac{1}{2})a}sh(\frac{\lambda a}{2})$$

You can observe the effects of n with this second expression.